Proving Non-Negativity of Solutions to a System of ODEs Involving Subsets
I’ve been working on the following problem for two months, and despite extensive effort and numerical simulations suggesting that the result should hold, I haven't been able to prove it analytically.
Let $ \mathcal{M}=\{ 1,2,...,M \} $. Consider the following system of ODEs defined for each non-empty subset $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{M}$:
$$
\frac{d\Psi_{\Omega}}{dt} + \left(\sum_{k_1\neq k_2 \in \Omega^c} A_{\Omega \cup \{k_1, k_2\}}\right)\Psi_{\Omega} = \sum_{k_1\neq k_2 \in \Omega^c} A_{\Omega \cup \{k_1, k_2\}} \left(\Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_1\}} + \Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_2\}} - \Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_1, k_2\}}\right) + f_{\Omega}(t), \qquad \Psi_{\Omega}(0) = 0.$$
Here, $A_{\Omega \cup \{k_1, k_2\}} \geq 0$  are constants, and $f_{\Omega}(t) \geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$. I want to prove that $\Psi_{\Omega}(t) \geq 0$ for all $t > 0$.
To approach this, I’ve tried finding the ODEs for $\Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_1\}} + \Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_2\}} - \Psi_{\Omega \cup \{k_1, k_2\}}$, but the equations quickly become very complicated, as these quantities in turn depend on other unknown quantities.
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
